# Перехват события развертывания узла JTree Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Как перехватить событие развертывания узла?

То есть при открытии узла дерева пользователем я бы хотел выполнить некоторое действие в параллельном потоке и лишь после этого действия развернуть узел.

Знаю, что для этого используется TreeWillExpandListener.

Знаю, что можно выбросить ExpandVetoException, но после этого уже узел развернуть не получается.

Надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Google по запросу "swing jtree expand listener" выдал мне [прекрасный пример](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JTree/Expand_Collapse_Expand_with_JTree_Lazy_loading.htm) обработчика открытия узла с выполнением некоторого действия в параллельном потоке:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeWillExpandListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.ExpandVetoException;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class LazyTree {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
    PropertyChangeListener progressListener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        bar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
      }
    };

    MyTreeNode root = new MyTreeNode(1, 0);
    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
    tree.addTreeWillExpandListener(new TreeWillExpandListener() {
      @Override
      public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException {
        TreePath path = event.getPath();
        if (path.getLastPathComponent() instanceof MyTreeNode) {
          MyTreeNode node = (MyTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
          node.loadChildren(model, progressListener);
        }
      }
      @Override
      public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent event)
          throws ExpandVetoException {

      }
    });
    tree.setModel(model);
    root.loadChildren(model, progressListener);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    frame.add(bar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MyTreeNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
  boolean loaded = false;
  int depth;
  int index;

  public MyTreeNode(int index, int depth) {
    this.index = index;
    this.depth = depth;
    add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Loading...", false));
    setAllowsChildren(true);
    setUserObject("Index " + index + " at level " + depth);
  }

  private void setChildren(List<MyTreeNode> children) {
    removeAllChildren();
    setAllowsChildren(children.size() > 0);
    for (MutableTreeNode node : children) {
      add(node);
    }
    loaded = true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLeaf() {
    return false;
  }

  public void loadChildren(final DefaultTreeModel model, final PropertyChangeListener progressListener) {
    if (loaded) {
      return;
    }

    SwingWorker<List<MyTreeNode>, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<List<MyTreeNode>, Void>() {
      @Override
      protected List<MyTreeNode> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        setProgress(0);
        List<MyTreeNode> children = new ArrayList<MyTreeNode>();
        if (depth < 5) {
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(300);
            children.add(new MyTreeNode(i + 1, depth + 1));
            setProgress((i + 1) * 20);
          }
        } else {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        setProgress(0);
        return children;
      }

      @Override
      protected void done() {
        try {
          setChildren(get());
          model.nodeStructureChanged(MyTreeNode.this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.done();
      }
    };

    if (progressListener != null) {
      worker.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener("progress", progressListener);
    }

    worker.execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я видел этот пример. Тут добавляются потомки к узлу, а у меня уже готовая модель файловой системы. Хотелось бы просто каким-то образом задержать развертывание узла до выполнения некоторой задачи в параллельном потоке.

Comment: Вам что-то мешает держать данные в памяти и выдавать дереву порциями при разворачивании узлов?